# How likely is a 5m passive USB 3 extension to work?

Tags: usb

I want to move my computer into another room for the summer, the destination is 10m away in terms of cable length. I had no problem finding a 10m HDMI 2.0 cable but USB 3.0 seems to be a different story.

Trying to do this as cheaply as possible, the current plan is to get a 5m active cable and attach another 5m passive cable to it to reach the hub on my desk. The reasoning being that the active cable is only active at one point - the female end of the cable which theoretically would be the same as a passive cable + hub at the end, right?

If the manufacturers of the active cable feel comfortable stretching the 3m specification to 5m then it.. might work?

Comment: Capable cable length is a function of the required throughput. Improved cable design can result in longer possible lengths.